# Open/Close sidenav from another component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I use angular (latest version) and angular material.

There are 3 components:

- header.component, in which there is a control button for right-sidenav
- rigth-sidenav.component, in which is the right-sidenav
- sidenav.component (this is the left main menu), this component calls header.component, right-sidenav.component and content

How to open / close sidenav from another component ? (in my case, the button is in header.component).

Tried the following option (but got the error: TypeError: this.RightSidenavComponent.rightSidenav is undefined):

*header.component.html*

```html
<button mat-button (click)="toggleRightSidenav()">Toggle side nav</button>
```

*header.component.ts*

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RightSidenavComponent } from '../right-sidenav/right-sidenav.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderComponent {

    constructor(public RightSidenavComponent:RightSidenavComponent) {   }
    toggleRightSidenav() {
        this.RightSidenavComponent.rightSidenav.toggle();
    }

}
```

*sidenav.component.html*

```html
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
    <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" opened="true" class="sidenav"
                 [fixedInViewport]="true"> Sidenav  </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content>
        <app-header></app-header>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        <app-right-sidenav #rSidenav></app-right-sidenav>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

*sidenav.component.ts*

```js
import { Component, Directive, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { RightSidenavComponent } from '../right-sidenav/right-sidenav.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidenav',
  templateUrl: './sidenav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidenav.component.scss']
})

export class SidenavComponent {

    @ViewChild('rSidenav') public rSidenav;
    constructor(public RightSidenavComponent: RightSidenavComponent) {
        this.RightSidenavComponent.rightSidenav = this.rSidenav;
    }

}
```

*right-sidenav.component.html*

```html
<mat-sidenav #rightSidenav mode="side" opened="true" class="rightSidenav"
             [fixedInViewport]="true" [fixedTopGap]="250">
    Sidenav
</mat-sidenav>
```

*right-sidenav.component.ts*

```js
import { Component, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-right-sidenav',
  templateUrl: './right-sidenav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./right-sidenav.component.scss']
})

@Injectable()
export class RightSidenavComponent {

    public rightSidenav: any;

    constructor() { }

}
```

[Non-working sample with code stackblitz](http://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6plaxw)

Comment: in right-sidenav.component.ts try changing `public rightSidenav: any;
` to `@ViewChild('rightSidenav') public rightSidenav: any;`

Comment: I think if you implement like this you need only one component for your right and left side nav (side nav)

Comment: i would also suggest you to format your question. The code snippet only works if its pure html , java script or css . check if its works in angular 2. So i could suggest you to remove and have proper formatting.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

I had the same problem using. I resolved it like this.

**SidenavService**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSidenav } from '@angular/material';

@Injectable()
export class SidenavService {
    private sidenav: MatSidenav;


    public setSidenav(sidenav: MatSidenav) {
        this.sidenav = sidenav;
    }

    public open() {
        return this.sidenav.open();
    }


    public close() {
        return this.sidenav.close();
    }

    public toggle(): void {
    this.sidenav.toggle();
   }
```

**Your Component**

```
constructor(
private sidenav: SidenavService) { }

toggleRightSidenav() {
   this.sidenav.toggle();
}
```

> Bind your html toggle() based on your requirement.

**App component.**

```
@ViewChild('sidenav') public sidenav: MatSidenav;

constructor(private sidenavService: SidenavService) {
}

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.sidenavService.setSidenav(this.sidenav);
}
```

**App Module**

```
providers: [YourServices , SidenavService],
```

[Working sample with code stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tku8zp)

**Angular 9+ Update**

Per [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58594324/3443552), "Components can no longer be imported through `@angular/material`. Use the individual secondary entry-points, such as `@angular/material/button.`"  As such, make sure to import `MatSidenav` like so:

```js
import { MatSidenav } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
```

Comment: Sorry. Did not quite understand. SidenavService is needed to operate the right-sidenav from header.component?

Comment: Sorry denis i missed to update the set side nav part; i have updated the code to include. The code is manuly typed from phne so please excuse for typo.

Comment: @Denis I have updated the answer. Please take a look & let me know ur feedback. If you have any suggestion to improve this or any new ideas happy to learn.

Comment: I do not know much Angular, so I did not succeed. Error: StaticInjectorError[SidenavService]

Comment: you have to add the service in module, @Denis I have updated the `app.module.ts` where you need to register the every service.
Try now

Comment: really, I forgot about it, but now another problem.If I add your code "Your Component" in the component where the control button is located, there is an error when clicking  'this.sidenav is undefined'. If  I add your code "Your Component" in the component where  is located right-sidenav: "TypeError: _co.toggleRightSidenav is not a function"

Comment: You dont need to add "Your Component" in to the code. Just use the `toggle()` in your header component.

Comment: You `toggleRightSidenav()` in your header component. Replace with the `sideNavservice.toggle()` it will work

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand how it works. Inserted and now the next error: TypeError: sidenav_service_1.SidenavService.toggle is not a function.

Comment: what is this `sidenav_service_1`? .

Comment: @ViewChild('sidenav') public sidenav: MatSidenav; in appComponent, but which one sidenav? I just have a two sidenav

Comment: give a unique name for your sidenav1 like `@ViewChild('sidenav1')`. Try one for now.

Comment: yes, I did so.  "what is this sidenav_service_1?" - it appeared after I toggleRightSidenav() {
   this.sidenav.toggle();
} replaced on toggleRightSidenav() {
   SidenavService.toggle();
}

Comment: Can you create a project here https://stackblitz.com/. So may be i can help you by editing it

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tku8zp please look this. I had implemented the basic way you can tweak it

Comment: Please mark as answer if its helped you. I would attach the sample to the answer.

Comment: If you could add your sample to question it will be easy for other people

Comment: How would you go about unit testing this by creating a mock MatSidenav?

Comment: I've used type assertion and a spy object : spyobject service["sidenav"] = <jasmine.SpyObj<MatSidenav>> jasmine.createSpyObj("sidenav", ["open", "close", "toggle"]);

Comment: I'm not sure about the unit test. But ideally your spyobject should able to detect the changes when you toggle from the component. I haven't done unit test in ang.

Comment: Thanks, Eldho. That's correct. I assigned a spy object to sidenav property of the SidenavService class. Thanks for your initial answer too - it was exactly what I was after.

Comment: @NathanBeck thanks if you have any suggestions to improve pls let me know

Comment: The only one that comes to mind is using `ngAfterViewInit()` instead of `ngOnInit()` - from this article https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-viewchild/ initializing the viewChild ensures "the references injected by @ViewChild are present".

Comment: @Eldho What is if i have 5 Sidenavs in different components? isnt there any way without registering something in app.component.ts?

Comment: @Budi How do you plan to use the sidenav components

Comment: I have alot `side-nav-container``s in my app... maybe 8? And all of them contains a sidenav. i need to trigger them from everywhere... I struggle for years with sidenav toggleing... I cant write in every component 10 lines or more of code just for a simple toggle...

Comment: Can you try to create a global side nav service and register all in one service and use it. Like rightsidenav.toggle()

Comment: As @NathanBeck mentions, if you get 'thissidenav is undefined' try using ngAfterViewInit instead of ngOnInit. This worked for me.

Comment: @tif i have updated the answer too `ngAfterViewInit`

Answer (score 37):

I used `@Input() inputSideNav: MatSideNav` in parent\ another component to pass the sideNav object as target property from child component. It works as expected. By the way, I liked the service implementation by @Eldho :)

1. It is simple to plugin in your current implementation
2. It is scalable to as many sideNav or other UI controls passed as reference into the component definition
3. No cluttering in code and plain as it looks.
4. Vote up if you get what we mean :)

Child.component.html

```
<app-layout-header [inputSideNav]="sideNav"></app-layout-header>
<mat-sidenav-container>
  <mat-sidenav #sideNav (click)="sideNav.toggle()" mode="side">
    <a routerLink="/">List Products</a>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

layout-header.component.html

```
<section>
  <mat-toolbar>
    <span (click)="inputSideNav.toggle()">Menu</span>
  </mat-toolbar>
</section>
```

layout-header.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSidenav } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-layout-header',
  templateUrl: './layout-header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./layout-header.component.css']
})
export class LayoutHeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() inputSideNav: MatSidenav;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this solution is simpler

Comment: I liked this solution but it does not work with my app component structure. The header component and sidenav component are sibling components, i.e. I call both app-header and app-sidenav under my app.component. This means the '#sidenav', which is inside my app-sidenave, cannot be passed to my app-header, any ideas?

Comment: @tif, I could not imagine your case. If possible, please post your code to stackblitz.

Comment: @tif, It looks like you fixed that problem. Could you please share your experience?

Comment: My case is like this: My app-component looks like this: <app-header><app-header><app-sidenav></app-sidenav><app-footer></app-footer> As you can see, 'sideNav is not exposed from app-sidenav. I actually solved using a service (from the answer marked for this question). Thanks for replying

Comment: @tif, but as you see this solution is exporting the #variable to parent component. Apparently, IMO, it is supposed to be available for siblings as well.

Comment: I've implemented this idea in Angular8, which works as I'm not using sibling components. But I am running into an ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError. Previous: 'sidenav: undefined', current value: 'sidenav: [object Object]'. Was this an issue for you @AshokanSivapragasam?

Usually I'd deal with this in the component class, but as it's injected in the template I'm not sure where or how to address it.

Comment: @nospi, could you please post your code to stackblitz?

Comment: @AshokanSivapragasam I'm unable to reproduce the error in a simplified StackBlitz so it must be something I've introduced. I'll post back if I find the cause. Cheers!

Comment: @AshokanSivapragasam Found it: I was passing a ViewChild reference via the component controller, instead of the #variable directly through the template.

Comment: If this style is applied, it is simpler to implement without altering your design

Comment: In angular10+ I get "sideNav has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor."Anyway to initialize the sideNav?

Comment: I found this article. Please check the solutions provided here and see if it helps by changing the severity of TS Lint. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49699067/property-has-no-initializer-and-is-not-definitely-assigned-in-the-construc

Comment: SIMPLE AND SMART SOLUTION

Comment: @wwjdm Latest version of typescript has 'strictPropertyInitialization' enabled by default. You can either disable it or add an ! as postfix to the variable name. For the example provided in the answer, it would be @Input() inputSideNav!: MatSidenav . Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49699067/property-has-no-initializer-and-is-not-definitely-assigned-in-the-construc

Answer (score 9):

If you are working in Angular 9+ Remember add param of `static: true` in `@ViewChild` like:

`@ViewChild('rightSidenav', {static: true}) sidenav: MatSidenav;`

You can see my code working on Angular 9 here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kwfinn-matsidenav-angular9

Answer (score 6):

For an easier solution just use an @ouput() event emitter.

In your parent component

```
 <mat-sidenav
    #sidenav
    class="sidenav"
    fixedInViewport
    [opened]="opened"
    [mode]="mode"
  >
// catch the emitted output from child component 
<childcomponent (sidenav)="sidenav.toggle()"></childcomponent>
....
</mat-sidenav>
```

child component

```
<mat-toolbar>
 <div>
  <button mat-button (click)="toggle()">
   <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
  </button>
 </div>
</mat-toolbar>
```

child component.ts

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, Output} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'childcomponent',
  templateUrl: './childcomponent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./childcomponent.component.scss'],
})
export class ChildComponent {
 @Output() sidenav: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

toggle() {
 this.sidenav.emit();
 }
}
```

Comment: This is an elegant and simple solution. Thank you ;)

Answer (score 1):

Though people above has already answered, but I believe my solution is more simple when I solved for myself.

You need to have a service in middle to support both components.

Let's say, such service is `NavService`, below code goes into `NavService`:

```
public toggleNav: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  public toggle(): void {
    this.toggleNav.next(!this.toggleNav.value);
  }
```

Then you have a component from where you would like to open or close your `SideNav`. In my case, I created the button in the `Navbar` as:

```
button *ngIf="this.loginService.tokenSubject.value"  mat-mini-fab color="warn" (click)="onToggle()"><mat-icon>menu</mat-icon></button>
```

Then in the `SideNavComponent` that you would have created for `SideNav`, put this in the `mat-sidenav` tag:

```
[opened]="this.sideNavService.toggleNav.value"
```

Of course, I injected the NavService as sideNavService in the constructor of this component.

Comment: Although this works, a BS should really be used publish to many (potential) subscribers. Since there is only ever one sidenav, having a common layout service with explicit open/close methods may be better than a BS that will only be subscribe to once.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need to toggle the right sidenav in the sidenav component.
Your toggle button is in the header component, so you can do this in your header component.

**header.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RightSidenavComponent } from '../right-sidenav/right-sidenav.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderComponent {
  rightSidenav: boolean;
  constructor(public RightSidenavComponent:RightSidenavComponent) { }

  toggleRightSidenav() {
    this.rightSidenav = !this.rightSidenav;
  }
}
```

And in your **header.component.html**, use this code:

```html
<app-right-sidenav *ngIf="rightSideNav"></app-right-sidenav>
```

This will make your work easy.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that with this solution the markup for the sidenav will not be rendered. This can impact SEO for the site, since the code for the navigation will not be found by the search enginges.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Eldho's answer, you can disable animations for a true hiding effect.

```
    <mat-sidenav #leftbar opened mode="side" class="ng-sidenav" [@.disabled]="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

to expanded on eldho service response I had an error when clicking
this.sidenav is undefined' I fixed it by making sure my Side nav was tagged with #sidenav to match the selector on the app.component.ts file.

Also mat-drawer-container and mat-drawer seems to be the new name for sidenav

```
<mat-drawer-container autosize>
   <mat-drawer #sidenav class="example-sidenav" mode="side" position="end">
    
   </mat-drawer>

   <mat-drawer-content autosize="true">
   
   </mat-drawer-content>
</mat-drawer-container>
```

the app.component.ts

```
@ViewChild('sidenav') public sidenav: MatSidenav;
```

Answer (score 0):

For a versatile and adaptable solution applicable to various scenarios, including but not limited to side-nav event management, is using [NgEventBus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-event-bus?activeTab=readme).

Steps:

1. **Component That Has Access to the SideNav:**

   This component is responsible for toggling the MatSidenav based on a specific event.

   ```js
   import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
   import { MatSidenav } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
   import { NgEventBus } from 'ng-event-bus';

   @Component({
     ...
   })
   export class ComponentThatHasAccessToTheSideNav {
     @ViewChild(MatSidenav) matSidenav: MatSidenav;

     constructor(private eventBus: NgEventBus) {}

     ngOnInit() {
       this.eventBus.on('appBarMenuButtonClickedEvent').subscribe(() => this.matSidenav.toggle());
     }
   }
   ```
2. **Component That Has the Toggle Button:**

   This component triggers the event that the other component listens for, leading to the toggling of the MatSidenav.

   ```js
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';
   import { NgEventBus } from 'ng-event-bus';

   @Component({
      ...
   })
   export class ComponentThatHasTheToggleButton {
     constructor(private eventBus: NgEventBus) {}

     menuClick() {
       this.eventBus.cast('appBarMenuButtonClickedEvent');
     }
   }
   ```

By adopting this approach, there's no need to create a new service for each similar use case. Moreover, multiple subscribers can listen to specific events.

Answer (score 0):

**Angular 17 version**
...but the idea is for basically any previous one

1. Set a template reference to the sidenav component

```
    <mat-sidenav-container>
      <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="side">I'm a sidenav</mat-sidenav>
      <mat-sidenav-content>Some content</mat-sidenav-content>
    </mat-sidenav-container>
```

2. Expose a toggle method

```
@Component({
  selector: 'elo-admin',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, MatSidenavModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatSelectModule, MatButtonModule],
  templateUrl: './admin.component.html',
  styleUrl: './admin.component.scss',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class AdminComponent {
  @ViewChild('sidenav') sidenav!: MatSidenav;

  private cdr = inject(ChangeDetectorRef);

  toggle() {
    this.sidenav.toggle();
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }

}
```

3. Place the nav component into parent, set a reference, get access to the public method of the referenced component

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <button (click)="admin.toggle()">toggle</button>
</mat-toolbar>
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <elo-admin #admin />
  <mat-card>
    <mat-card-content>
      <router-outlet />
    </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

NOTE: I've been stuck for a while due to change detection, you need to trigger it manually after toggle().