# Property '...' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor

Tags: angular, typescript

in my Angular app i have a component:

```
import { MakeService } from './../../services/make.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-vehicle-form',
  templateUrl: './vehicle-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./vehicle-form.component.css']
})
export class VehicleFormComponent implements OnInit {
  makes: any[];
  vehicle = {};

  constructor(private makeService: MakeService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.makeService.getMakes().subscribe(makes => { this.makes = makes
      console.log("MAKES", this.makes);
    });
  }

  onMakeChange(){
    console.log("VEHICLE", this.vehicle);
  }
}
```

but in the "makes" property I have a mistake. 
I dont know what to do with it...

[image: mistake]

Comment: I am wondering: On newer versions of TypeScript, did anyone figured it out how to specify the object type that will reside inside the array? Instead of using Any[]... ✍

Answer (score 381, accepted):

I think you are using the latest version of TypeScript. Please see the section "Strict Class Initialization" in the **[`link`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html)**.

There are two ways to fix this:

A. If you are using VSCode you need to change the TS version that the editor use.

B. Just initialize the array when you declare it

```
makes: any[] = [];
```

or inside the constructor:

```
constructor(private makeService: MakeService) { 
   // Initialization inside the constructor
   this.makes = [];
}
```

Comment: as the error says you need to initialize the variable to some value makes: any[] = [];

Comment: You must use 'Definite Assignment Assertion' to tell typescript that this variable will have a value at runtime as follows: `makes!: any[];`

Comment: HI @Sajeetharan, how to chnage vscode ts version

Comment: Initializing variables in the constructor is an Angular anti-pattern. Don't do it.

Comment: @KumaresanSd `ctrl+shift+p` and type `typescript` in the dropdown, then select "Select TypeScript Version"

Comment: @WillAlexander So why Angular Docs say _"the recommended solution is to use a constructor or ngOnInit to set initial values"_ ([src](https://angular.io/errors/NG0100#debugging-the-error)) or _"Constructors should do no more than set the initial local variables to simple values."_ ([src](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#initializing-a-component-or-directive))?

Comment: @MartinSchneider your first source, in context, makes sense. It’s saying “you’re using the wrong lifecycle hook”. Your second source says “no more than”, meaning they can also do less. In practice, putting any logic in constructors has a tendency to make code less clean, as one expects all initializations to be done in ngOnInit. Perhaps it would be more correct of me to call it code smell, rather than an anti-pattern. Still, it’s not good practice.

Comment: @HusseinAkar Hello! What do you mean? I am using ngOnInit to populate this array of objects of the `interface` type. So I need to include the `!` after the variable declaration, because of that?

Comment: Where did this MakeService come from?

Comment: I tried this multiple times and using multiple ways and can not get it to work. 

Comment: @RaulChiarella Hello!!, If you have strict mode enabled, and you don't give a value declared on initialisation, one way to is to include ! after the variable name. example: 
makes: any[]; //doesn't work
makes!: any[]; // should work fine 

In the second example you telling the IDE that you are sure this value will be declared before being used.

Answer (score 1569):

Just go to **tsconfig.json** and set

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    ...
}
```

to get rid of the compilation error.

Otherwise you need to initialize all your variables which is a little bit annoying

Comment: Just make sure you add that after "strict": true else the transpiler seems to turn it on again (although VS seems to know it's off).

Comment: In this way you will disable the strict checking property initialization for all the project. It's better to add the `!` postfix operator to the variable name, to just ignore this case, or initialize the variable inside the constructor.

Comment: You are suggesting to ignore potential problems that the compiler is telling about, this is not really safe. So downvote.

Comment: StrictPropertyInitialzer is a flag introduced in typescript 2.7. It's up to everybody to choose if you want to enable all these flags and strictly follow all rules or turn off some validation. It makes completely no sense to follow all the rules every time. If your code gets too verbose and downsides and are bigger than advantages you should definetly turn it off. I am not telling that this is the best practice in all cases but its definetly viable option in most cases...

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer you have two options either you disable validation OR initialize all variables. Its up to everybody to choose what will you benefit more from project to project.

Comment: when I set it to false it still gives me the same error, what might be the issue? I'm using VS Code

Comment: I thought the whole point of TypeScript was to avoid doing this kind of thing. Wouldn't you at least want to assign `undefined` or `null` or something?

Comment: After adding, I needed to restart vsCode to solve it.

Comment: Thanks! In `tsconfig.json` .. `compilerOptions` ... I updated the value of strict from true to false ... `"strict": false`     and it fixed the issue.

Comment: For anyone else wondering, this entry has to be added in the "compilerOptions" parts of tsconfig.json

Comment: avoid at all costs removing/disabling compiler or lint options if you are deploying for production

Comment: wow ts won't let you work around this garbage with this.field = null in the constructor either.  thanks ts for forcing me to choose bogus initial values for everything, so helpful

Comment: This advice is technically an option, but typically inadvisable, because it reduces the effectiveness of TypeScript and overall code quality could go down as a result.

In my opinion, this approach is akin to using a sledge hammer to put a screw in a wall... yeah, the screw will go in, but you're also going to damage the wall in the process, and the screw probably isn't going to secure anything effectively anyway.

Comment: Most of the time it's better to use hammer that you are used to and put screw gently in to the wall so you don't do any damage than have twenty different tools not knowing to use properly even one of them and in the process damage the wall, the screw and yourself.

Comment: I think this is a design error of typeorm. Even if you disable it with a `!` you can assign a null that value. It is not required in the constructor anymore... The fact that they do not mention it in their documentation tells already the story.

Comment: As suggested by Matteo Guarnerio, it is best to add ! to assert that this particular variable will be initialized for sure rather than using compiler options to disable the check for the entire application

Comment: Leandro, propertyInitialization option was added later in typescript as a compiler check option. Does that mean that before that all the written code was wrong because typescript didnt force you to do this ? Its up to everybody to choose his standarts / rules on his particular project. What works best for you and what you agreed on as a team to follow. If you dont want to turn off this check feel free to do it the other way. What works for you doesnt mean is the best way for all of us. We have a choice.

Comment: Terrible advice, downvote.

Comment: Good suggestion I prefer this approach compared to marking the variable with `!` or initialising. Especially for subscriptions that take place on OnInit.

Answer (score 347):

It is because TypeScript 2.7 includes a strict class checking where all the properties should be initialized in the constructor. A workaround is to add 
 the `!` as a postfix to the variable name:

```
makes!: any[];
```

Comment: The "!" syntax exists for those common-ish cases where you can't guarantee that the value will be defined immediately. It's an escape hatch, and shouldn't be relied on, as it can make your code less safe. A default value is usually preferred. Good to know it exists, though

Comment: @kingdaro is right.  While this can generally be used, it can also lead to code that flat doesn't work.  As an example, in the basic webapp generated by VS2017, change the assignment for the forecasts in fetchdata.components.ts by adding the '!' (public forecasts!: WeatherForecast[];) and it will cause it to completely error out

Comment: This is the best solution, since it is directly after the @Input() decorator (in the new angular), when reading any given component, it reads naturally and culls out any dev mistakes.

Comment: incidentally what is the difference from using ! or ? to handle nulls or undefined?

Comment: I needed to define a property that uses an Enum in a service on an app where I can't assume the user's choices, not even a default. It is defined in the first step and not read until the second, so this was very useful escape, good to know it exists, thanks very much.

Comment: This is not recommended when the property is assigned within a subscribe or async callback. There will be a short period of time where it is undefined and the template will throw errors. Use ?:

Answer (score 176):

We may get the message `Property has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor` when adding some configuration in the `tsconfig.json` file so as to have an Angular project compiled in strict mode:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "strict": true,
  "noImplicitAny": true,
  "noImplicitThis": true,
  "alwaysStrict": true,
  "strictNullChecks": true,
  "strictFunctionTypes": true,
  "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
```

Indeed the compiler then complains that a member variable is not defined before being used.

For an example of a member variable that is not defined at compile time, a member variable having an `@Input` directive:

```
@Input() userId: string;
```

We could silence the compiler by stating the variable may be optional:

```
@Input() userId?: string;
```

But then, we would have to deal with the case of the variable not being defined, and clutter the source code with some such statements:

```
if (this.userId) {
} else {
}
```

Instead, knowing the value of this member variable would be defined in time, that is, it would be defined before being used, we can tell the compiler not to worry about it not being defined.

The way to tell this to the compiler is to add the `! definite assignment assertion` operator, as in:

```
@Input() userId!: string;
```

Now, the compiler understands that this variable, although not defined at compile time, shall be defined at run-time, and in time, before it is being used.

It is now up to the application to ensure this variable is defined before being used.

As an an added protection, we can assert the variable is being defined, before we use it.

We can assert the variable is defined, that is, the required input binding was actually provided by the calling context:

```
private assertInputsProvided(): void {
  if (!this.userId) {
    throw (new Error("The required input [userId] was not provided"));
  }
}

public ngOnInit(): void {
  // Ensure the input bindings are actually provided at run-time
  this.assertInputsProvided();
}
```

Knowing the variable was defined, the variable can now be used:

```
ngOnChanges() {
  this.userService.get(this.userId)
    .subscribe(user => {
      this.update(user.confirmedEmail);
    });
}
```

Note that the `ngOnInit` method is called after the input bindings attempt, this, even if no actual input was provided to the bindings.

Whereas the `ngOnChanges` method is called after the input bindings attempt, and only if there was actual input provided to the bindings.

Comment: this is the correct answer when using 'strict' mode

Comment: A lot of this makes sense to me apart from one thing... What would the assert give you? Would be fine for debugging, but not for using the app. Throwing errors that will not be caught is not a good idea. You should provide some fallback that will make things work no matter what.

Comment: This should be upvoted as the correct answer, as it solves the problem, rather than just turning of part of the linting.

Comment: Using "definite assignment assertion" in strict mode just to avoid the condition checks doesn't make great sense. You are undermining the whole logic of having a strict typed system. If avoiding those checks is more important to you, then you probably shouldn't use strict mode.

Answer (score 130):

Go to your `tsconfig.json` file and change  the property:

```
 "noImplicitReturns": false
```

and then add

```
 "strictPropertyInitialization": false
```

under `"compilerOptions"` property.

Your `tsconfig.json` file should looks like:

```json
{
      ...
      "compilerOptions": {
            ....
            "noImplicitReturns": false,
            ....
            "strictPropertyInitialization": false
      },
      "angularCompilerOptions": {
         ......
      }  
 }
```

> Hope this will help !!

> **Good Luck**

Comment: IMO, it is kinda going backward.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the solution, it worked. Secondly, can anyone explain what just happened?

Comment: It worked ,  it is necessary when creating directives in angular.

Answer (score 87):

The error is **legitimate** and may prevent your app from crashing. You typed `makes` as an array but it can also be undefined.

You have 2 options (instead of disabling the typescript's reason for existing...):

**1.** In your case the best is to type `makes` as possibily undefined.

```
makes?: any[]
// or
makes: any[] | undefined
```

So the compiler will inform you whenever you try to access to `makes` that it could be undefined.
Otherwise, if the `// <-- Not ok` lines below were executed before `getMakes` finished or if `getMakes` failed, your app would crash and a runtime error would be thrown. That's definitely not what you want.

```
makes[0] // <-- Not ok
makes.map(...) // <-- Not ok

if (makes) makes[0] // <-- Ok
makes?.[0] // <-- Ok
(makes ?? []).map(...) // <-- Ok
```

**2.** You can assume that it will never fail and that you will never try to access it before initialization by writing the code below (risky!). So the compiler won't take care about it.

```
makes!: any[]
```

---

---

**More specifically,**

Your code's design warrants improvement. Best practices discourage the use of locally defined and mutable variables. A more effective approach involves managing data storage within a service:

- To ensure null/undefined safety,
- To factorise code (including typing, loading state and errors),
- To control unnecessary re-fetch across components.

Here's an illustrative example of the concept I'm proposing. Please note that I have not tested it, and there is room for further improvement.

```
type Make = any // Type it

class MakeService {

  private readonly source = new BehaviorSubject<Make[] | undefined>(undefined);
  loading = false;

  private readonly getMakes = (): Observable<Make[]> => {
    /* ... your current implementation */
  };

  readonly getMakes2 = () => {
    if (this.source.value) {
      return this.source.asObservable();
    }
    return new Observable(_ => _.next()).pipe(
      tap(_ => {
        this.loading = true;
      }),
      mergeMap(this.getMakes),
      mergeMap(data => {
        this.source.next(data);
        return data;
      }),
      tap(_ => {
        this.loading = false;
      }),
      catchError((err: any) => {
        this.loading = false;
        return throwError(err);
      }),
    );
  };
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-vehicle-form',
  template: `
    <div *ngIf="makeService.loading">Loading...</div>
    <div *ngFor="let vehicule of vehicules | async">
      {{vehicle.name}}
    </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./vehicle-form.component.css']
})
export class VehicleFormComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public makeService: MakeService) {}

  readonly makes = this.makeService.getMakes2().pipe(
    tap(makes => console.log('MAKES', makes))
  );

  readonly vehicules = this.makes.pipe(
    map(make => make/* some transformation */),
    tap(vehicule => console.log('VEHICLE', vehicule)),
  );

  ngOnInit() {
    this.makes.subscribe(makes => {
      console.log('MAKES', makes);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems like the only correct solution. I'm horrified by the other answers.

Comment: I also consider that this error message is useful. So deactivate it in tsconfig.json is not the appropriate solution. And adding '!' can allows the compiler to let go, but it makes the code less sure, unless you're really sure of what is going on. A better solution seems to understand that the property can be undedinfed, and therefore the developer has to write code accordingly. This is the purpose of the answer to me.

Comment: @Rei Miyasaka, this "feature" was added later to typescript does that mean that all code that was written before is wrong ? No it does not. When you have your hello world application feel free to follow all the rules. But once you have huge project (which is a reason for language like typescript to start with) then you should decide how to write the code and all should follow it. I don't see ANYTHING wrong with disabling this particular option in tsconfig.json.

Comment: @MartinČuka Just because everyone was doing it doesn't mean it wasn't wrong or that it wasn't horrifying. TypeScript itself was brought about because JavaScript is kind of horrifying. And the larger the project, the more you should want to be strict with type rules.

Comment: option 2 adding a `!` before `:` is more common.

Answer (score 47):

## there are many solutions

> demo code

```
class Plant {
  name: string;
  // ❌ Property 'name' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.ts(2564)
}
```

### solutions

1. add 'undefined' type

```
class Plant {
  name: string | undefined;
}
```

2. add definite assignment assertion

```
class Plant {
  name!: string;
}
```

3. declare with init value

```
class Plant {
  name: string = '';
}
```

4. use the constructor with an init value

```
class Plant {
  name: string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = '';
  }
}
```

5. use the constructor and init value by params

```
class Plant {
  name: string;
  constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name ?? '';
  }
}
```

6. shorthand of the `5`

```
class Plant {
  constructor(public name: string = name ?? '') {
    // 
  }
}
```

### tsconfig.json

> not recommended

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
+   "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
-   "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
  }
}
```

### refs

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#--strictpropertyinitialization

Answer (score 39):

1. Go to **tsconfig.json**
2. add **"strictPropertyInitialization": false,** in *"compilerOptions":*

[image]

Answer (score 26):

Update for 2021  :

> there is property like "strictPropertyInitialization"

Just go to tsconfig.json and set

**"strict": false**

to get rid of the compilation error.

Otherwise you need to initialize all your variables which is a little bit annoying.

reason behind this error is :

- typescript is a kind of more Secure lang  as compare to javascript.
- although this security is enhance by enabling **strict feature** .So every time when you initialize a variable typescript wants them to assign a value.

Comment: Horrible advice, throws out type safety so that you see fewer errors, rather than surrendering some convenience for safety.

Comment: Apparently, strict option is a combination of several strict type-checking options in TypeScript, including noImplicitAny, strictNullChecks, strictFunctionTypes, strictPropertyInitialization, noImplicitThis, and alwaysStrict. Maybe a bad idea to disable all of that?

Answer (score 23):

You either need to disable the `--strictPropertyInitialization` that
Sajeetharan referred to, or do something like this to satisfy the initialization requirement:

```
makes: any[] = [];
```

Answer (score 17):

You can also do the following if you really don't want to initialise it.

```
makes?: any[];
```

Answer (score 15):

A batter approach would be to add the exclamation mark to the end of the variable for which you are sure that it shall not be undefined or null, for instance you are using an ElementRef which needs to be loaded from the template and can't be defined in the constructor, do something like below

```
class Component {
 ViewChild('idname') variable! : ElementRef;
}
```

Answer (score 14):

If you want to initialize an **object based on an interface** you can initialize it empty with following statement.

```
myObj: IMyObject = {} as IMyObject;
```

Comment: Beware that this does not provide type safety. After doing this, typescript will assume that your object is complete while it is actually empty. A safer solution would be to use "myObj: Partial<IMyObject> = {};" which tells typescript that every property of the object may be undefined.

Answer (score 14):

Put a question (?) mark after *makes* variable.

```
  makes?: any[];
  vehicle = {};

  constructor(private makeService: MakeService) { }
```

It should now works.
I'm using angular 12 and it works on my code.

Answer (score 14):

if you don't want to change your **tsconfig.json**, you can define your class like this:

```
class Address{
  street: string = ''
}
```

or, you may proceed like this as well:

```
class Address{
  street!: string
}
```

by adding an exclamation mark "!" after your variable name, Typescript will be sure that this variable is not null or undefined.

Answer (score 12):

As of TypeScript 2.7.2, you are required to initialise a property in the constructor if it was not assigned to at the point of declaration.

If you are coming from Vue, you can try the following:

- Add `"strictPropertyInitialization": true` to your tsconfig.json
- If you are unhappy with disabling it you could also try this `makes: any[] | undefined`. Doing this requires that you access the properties with null check (`?.`) operator i.e. `this.makes?.length`
- You could as well try `makes!: any[];`, this tells TS that the value will be assigned at runtime.

Answer (score 10):

in **tsconfig.json** file , inside "compilerOptions" add :

```
"strictPropertyInitialization": false,
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Get this error at the time of adding Node in my Angular project -

> TSError: ? Unable to compile TypeScript:
> (path)/base.api.ts:19:13 - error TS2564: Property 'apiRoot
> Path' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.
>
> private apiRootPath: string;

Solution -

Added `"strictPropertyInitialization": false` in 'compilerOptions' of **tsconfig.json**.

my **package.json** -

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "@angular/common": "~10.1.3",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.9",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    ...
}
```

Ref URL - https://www.ryadel.com/en/ts2564-ts-property-has-no-initializer-typescript-error-fix-visual-studio-2017-vs2017/

Answer (score 8):

When you upgrade  using typescript@2.9.2 , its compiler strict the rules follows for array type declare inside the component class constructor.

For fix this issue either change the code where are declared in the code or avoid to compiler  to add property **"strictPropertyInitialization": false** in the **"tsconfig.json"** file  and run again npm start .

Angular web and mobile Application Development  you can go to www.jtechweb.in

Answer (score 8):

a new version of typescript has introduced strick class Initialization, that is means by all of the properties in your class you need to initialize in the constructor body, or by a property initializer. [check it in typescript doccumntation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#strict-class-initialization)
to avoid this you can add (! or  ?) with property

```
make!: any[] or make? : any[]
```

otherwise, if  you wish to remove strick class checking permanently in your project
you can set strictPropertyInitialization": false in tsconfig.json file

> "compilerOptions": {
> ....
> "noImplicitReturns": false,
> ....
> "strictPropertyInitialization": false
> },

Comment: What is the difference between '!' and '?' ?

Comment: @pouyada the `!` is assertive assignment declaration saying that no matter what it is assigned even if typescript can't pick it up. `?` is optional meaning it may or may not be there but your component should be prepared for either case.

Answer (score 8):

It is because typescript 2.7.2 included a strict class checking where all properties should be declared in constructor. So to work around that, just add an exclamation mark (!) like:

```
name!:string;
```

Answer (score 6):

Can't you just use a Definite Assignment Assertion? (See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#definite-assignment-assertions)

i.e. declaring the property as `makes!: any[];` The ! assures typescript that there definitely will be a value at runtime.

Sorry I haven't tried this in angular but it worked great for me when I was having the exact same problem in React.

Comment: Working with all versions since it is in the official documentation and I tried it. THANKS!!

Answer (score 6):

Another way to fix in the case when the variable must remain uninitialized (and it is dealt with at the run time) is to add `undefined` to the type (this is actually suggested by VC Code). Example:

```
@Input() availableData: HierarchyItem[] | undefined;
@Input() checkableSettings: CheckableSettings | undefined;
```

Depending on actual usage, this might lead to other issues, so I think the best approach is to initialize the properties whenever possible.

Comment: Worked for me when initializing the @ViewChild variable.. see for reference: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-flow-example?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Writing `@Input() availableData: HierarchyItem[] | undefined;` is the same as writing `@Input() availableData?: HierarchyItem[]` ;)

Answer (score 6):

This has been discussed in Angular Github at https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24571

I think this [recommendation from angular](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24571#issuecomment-404606595) gives good advice:

> For angular components, use the following rules in deciding between:
> a) adding initializer
> b) make the field optional `?`
> c) leave the `!`
>
> - If the field is annotated with `@input` - Make the field optional b) or
>   add an initializer a).
> - If the input is required for the component user - add an assertion in `ngOnInit` and apply c).
> - If the field is annotated `@ViewChild`, `@ContentChild`  - Make the field optional b).
> - If the field is annotated with `@ViewChildren` or `@ContentChildren` - Add back '!' - c).
> - Fields that have an initializer, but it lives in `ngOnInit`. - Move the initializer to the constructor a).
> - Fields that have an initializer, but it lives in `ngOnInit` and cannot be moved because it depends on other `@input` fields - Add back '!' - c).

Answer (score 6):

**1) You can apply it like the code below. When you do this, the system will not give an error.**

"Definite Assignment Assertion" **(!)** to tell TypeScript that we know this value

[Detail info](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3539-using-the-definite-assignment-assertion-to-define-required-input-bindings-in-angular-7-1-1.htm)

```
@Injectable()
export class Contact {
  public name !:string;
  public address!: Address;
  public digital!: Digital[];
  public phone!: Phone[];
}
```

**2) The second method is to create a constructor and define values here.**

```
export class Contact {
  public name :string;
  public address: Address;
  public digital: Digital[];
  public phone: Phone[];

  constructor( _name :string,
     _address: Address,
     _digital: Digital[],
     _phone: Phone[])
  {
    this.name=_name;
    this.address=_address;
    this.digital=_digital;
    this.phone=_phone;
  }
}
```

**3) The third choice will be to create a get property and assign a value as follows**

```
  export class Contact {
      public name :string="";
      public address: Address=this._address;
    
      get _address(): Address {
        return new Address();
      }
     
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

In my case it works with different declaration according new typescript strict features:

```
@ViewChild(MatSort, {static: true}) sort!: MatSort;
```

If disable typescript new strict feature in tsonfig.json with

```
"compilerOptions": {
  ///
  ,
  "strictPropertyInitialization":false
}
```

the old Angular's guide code works well

```
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
```

Here is 4 ways to solve the issue thanks to
Arunkumar Gudelli (2022) https://www.angularjswiki.com/angular/property-has-no-initializer-and-is-not-definitely-assigned-in-the-constructor/

Answer (score 2):

Add these two line on the tsconfig.json

```
"noImplicitReturns": true,
"strictPropertyInitialization": false,
```

and make sure strict is set to true

Answer (score 2):

JUST go to the **tsconfig.ts** and add
**"strictPropertyInitialization": false,** into the **compilerOptions** Object .

- if it doesn't solve yet, kindly re-open your Code Editor.

EXAMPLE:

```
"compilerOptions" : {
  "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change the

```
fieldname?: any[];
```

to this:

```
fieldname?: any;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare property in constructor like this:

```
export class Test {
constructor(myText:string) {
this.myText= myText;
} 

myText: string ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A little late for the party. but the most voted answer includes changing the security level as a whole abandoning type safety, to work around this use the typing mechanism of the typescript itself

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator | undefined;

ngAfterViewInit() { 
  this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator as MatPaginator;
}
```

I believe the angular material documentation should be updated, but until then I believe this is the best way to do it

Answer (score 0):

Follow 2 steps to solve this::

1. "strictPropertyInitialization": false entry in tsconfig.json
2. ctrl+c stop your server on Terminal(check for terminal, where it is running) and run it again with the command you use like ng serve
   These 2 steps, should solve your issue.. as it solved mine.. cheers.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of turning off the strict mode, you can assign a initial value to the variable.
For example:

1. `makes: any[] = [null];`
2. `private year: number = 0;`

Answer (score -2):

You can also add @ts-ignore to silence the compiler only for this case:

```
//@ts-ignore
makes: any[];
```

Answer (score -3):

Comment the `//"strict": true` line in **tsconfig.json** file.

Comment: Need strict, also have the same issue. I am trying to include this will work other wise shows error

Answer (score -3):

Just declare your variable as type any

```
@Input() headerName: any;
```

Answer (score -4):

Next to variables  "?" You can fix it by putting it.

Example:

**--------->id?:number
--------->name?:string**