# Angular with PHP backend

Tags: angular, backend, angular-httpclient

i will combine an angular app with a php backend - but somehow my variable "intrologos" is shown as 'wrong' ... the "intrologos" befor the ":" ...
additionally thr "res['data']" is shown as false ...

```
export class IntroLogosService {
  baseUrl = 'http://localhost/backend';
  intrologos: IntroLogos[];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  getAll(): Observable<IntroLogos[]> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/listintrologos`).pipe(
      map((res) => {
        this.intrologos = res['data'];
        return this.intrologos;
    }));
  }
}
```

the IntroLogos class is imported ...
someone an idea?  Thanks!

Comment: How is it shown as "wrong"? Lint issue, because you don't cast response as any type?

Comment: 'The property "intrologos" has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor' is the first error ... the second is "the name res was not found".

Comment: I think that it might be a problem with tsconfig - could you check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49699067/property-has-no-initializer-and-is-not-definitely-assigned-in-the-construc ?

Comment: "intrologos: IntroLogos[] = [];" is the solution for the first error. the second error (on "res['data']") is still there

Comment: at compiling the second error is shown as:
"error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"data"' can't be used to index type 'Object'."

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have statefull service (it will work as a cache), then you should just add `subscribe` at the very end:

```
export class IntroLogosService {
  baseUrl = 'http://localhost/backend';
  intrologos: IntroLogos[];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  fetchAndSaveInTheServiceAsCach(): void {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/listintrologos`).pipe(
      map((res) => res.data)
    ).subscribe( 
      intrologos -> this.intrologos = intrologos;
    }));
  }
}
```

On the other hand, if you the service to not be a cache and just return the value of intrologos, look at this:

```
export class IntroLogosService {
  baseUrl = 'http://localhost/backend';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAll(): Observable<IntroLogos[]> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/listintrologos`).pipe(
      map((res) => res.data)
    );
  }
}
```

And then you can subscribe (or even better - use the async pipe) in any other service/component.

Comment: thank you for your answer. but your answer does not contain an answer to my question why the "intrologos: IntroLogos[];" gives me an error message on the "intrologos" variable before the ":" - and don't matter which of your solutions i try both are not working because they give errors. Whats wrong? Something missing in my project?

Comment: Can you share what is the json output if you'll try to call the endpoint manually (eg using Postman)?

Comment: the output is:
{"0":{"Name":"Einr1","Ort":"OrtEinr1","Logo":"LogoEinr1.jpg"},"1":{"Name":"Einr2","Ort":"OrtEinr2","Logo":"LogoEinr2.jpg"}}

Comment: i changed something and now the output is: {"data":[{"Name":"Einr1","Ort":"OrtEinr1","Logo":"LogoEinr1.jpg"},{"Name":"Einr2","Ort":"OrtEinr2","Logo":"LogoEinr2.jpg"}]}
i don't understand the error on "res['data']" which tells: "error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"data"' can't be used to index type 'Object'. Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Object'."