# Angular error TS2564: Property 'users' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using angular to built this app using this example from "https://coursetro.com/posts/code/171/Angular-7-Tutorial---Learn-Angular-7-by-Example".
Its an exact code but I am still getting an error for **"user:Object"**

**How can I fix this error?**

> error TS2564: Property 'users' has no initializer and is not
> definitely assigned in the constructor.
>
> 12   users: Object;
> ~~~~~

```
Here is the exact code as per website:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  //h1Style:boolean = false;

  users: Object;

  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.data.getUsers().subscribe(data => {
        this.users = data
        console.log(this.users);
      }
    );
  }


}
```

My Angular based on ng version:
Angular CLI: 11.1.2

Node: 14.15.4

OS: win32 x64

Angular: 11.1.1

... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms

... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                         Version

---

@angular-devkit/architect       0.1101.2

@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1101.2

@angular-devkit/core            11.1.2

@angular-devkit/schematics      11.1.2

@angular/cli                    11.1.2

@schematics/angular             11.1.2

@schematics/update              0.1101.2

rxjs                            6.6.3

typescript                      4.1.3

Comment: Try lowercase object...

Comment: same error even with lowercase object

Comment: It isn't an error per se, more of a Typescript warning that you're not initializing this property, which as a result could be undefined at runtime. You can ignore it as the code should compile as-is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Property '...' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49699067/property-has-no-initializer-and-is-not-definitely-assigned-in-the-construc)

Comment: sorry still getting error based on the example tutorial. it wont let me run with user:Object. if i remove it runs fine

Answer (score 21):

As `@alcfeoh` pointed out in the comments, you are getting this error because you are defining a variable but not declaring a value for it. The short answer is if you don't want to declare a value, then... [just bang it](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Vue-Starter/issues/36):

```
users!: Object;
```

The reason why typescript throws this error is to prevent the following:

```
someNumber: number;
```

If there is no declaration included then the value of `someNumber` will be undefined even though we have explicitly not listed this type as `someNumber: number | undefined;`. But in many other languages, someNumber would receive a default value like `0`. However that is not how Javascript works. If in this scenario you were to do `someNumber + 1` the result would be `null`.

Comment: Alternatively, you can initialize it with an empty object: `users: object = {};`

Comment: Indeed, as @LindaPaiste says: I got my complaints on a `@Input() someProp: string`, and extending this with a default value `@Input() someProp: string=""` is perfectly fine for me...

Answer (score 14):

u should add this code below tsconfig.json/"compilerOptions"

```
"strictPropertyInitialization": false,
```

Comment: You will need to restart the server (ng serve) after this.