# TS2564: Property 'signupForm' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor

Tags: angular, angular8

I'm using **ViewChild** for angular form submit. This is my code,

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    @ViewChild('f') signupForm: NgForm; 

    onSubmit(){
        console.log(this.signupForm);
    }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate></form>
```

But I'm getting this error,

> src/app/app.component.ts:11:21 - error TS2564: Property 'signupForm'
> has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.
>
> 11     @ViewChild('f') signupForm: NgForm;

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Property '...' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49699067/property-has-no-initializer-and-is-not-definitely-assigned-in-the-construc)

Comment: I tried adding constructor like that but didn't work :(

Comment: What version of TypeScript are you using? [Strict Class Initialization](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html)

Comment: It's looks like work in a simple stackblitz:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7b3a3e?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts (check if you're import FormsModule in your module or try use `@ViewChild('f') signupForm: NgForm=null;`

Comment: I have added **FormsModule** inside `app.module.ts` and tried `@ViewChild('f') signupForm: NgForm=null;` too now but unfortunately didn't work :'(

Comment: Think I have `"typescript": "~4.1.5"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally found an answer. I had to make `strictPropertyInitialization` flag to `false` inside **tsconfig.json**. Adding this since someone came up with same issue would find this useful. (You may have to use ***ng serve*** again)

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You could also do this:

```
@ViewChild('f') signupForm!: NgForm;
```

With the `!` operator you basically say: I know what I'm doing and I know that angular will set this value for me. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43891263/2099661) for more information about the operator.

Comment: This fixes the error message but doesn't work by refocusing the input. @vimuth answer doesn't fix the error highlighting message but works like charm by focusing the input correctly. Tested in Angular 12+