# Property is not populating

Tags: angular11

I am learning Angular 11. I am following [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-carousel-with-angular-animations) code. My code is like below.

**carousel.interface.ts**

```
export interface Slide {
  headline?: string;
  src: string;
}
```

**carousel.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Slide } from './carousel.interface';

@Component({
  selector    : 'carousel',
  templateUrl : './carousel.component.html',
  styleUrls   : ['./carousel.component.scss'],
})

export class CarouselComponent {

  @Input() slides: Slide[]; 

  currentSlide = 0;

  constructor() { }
}
```

Are `{ Slide }` and `Slide[]` same ? If same then why `slides` is not populating ?

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49699067/property-has-no-initializer-and-is-not-definitely-assigned-in-the-construc) SO post. But I think issue of that post is different.

Comment: No. The `{ Slide }` indicate in your import statement, to just import the `Slide` variable/interface/class/function/type from the given folder. `Slide[]` indicate the type of the property `slides` of `CarouselComponent` class is an array of `Slide`. Since it is decorated with `@Input` you should provide the `slides` array from the parent component. ( `from app component` )

Comment: Thanks @Dilshan. How can I provide the slides array from the parent component. ( from app component ) ? There is `slides: Slide[] =
    [
      {
        headline: 'Miouw',
            src: 'sometext'
      },
      {
        headline: 'In The Wilderness',
          src: 'sometext'
      },
      {
        headline: 'For Your Current Mood',
          src: 'sometext'
      },
      {
        headline: 'Focus On The Writing',
        src: 'sometext'
      }
    ]` in `app.component.ts`. Is it enough ?  What is `@Input` here ? Thanks.

Comment: Check the line number 2 of `app.component.html` in the code you are following. The actual `slides` array is defined inside the `app.component.ts` line 33. That's the one you provide to the child component `carousel` via an `@Input()`. Here's some information about `@Input`. https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs

Comment: Thanks @Dilshan. I am learning Angular 11. Why I am getting `Property 'slides' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.` error in this line `@Input() slides: Slide[];` ? Thanks.

Comment: open the `tsconfig.json` and set `"strictPropertyInitialization": false` or else add `!` to the end of the variable like, `@Input() slide! : Slide[]`