# Property 'updateModf' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor

Tags: angular, typescript

i have an angular reactive form, so when i declare a variable withe a FormGroup type like this :

```
  updateModf:FormGroup;
```

, the IDE shows me this error:

```
Property 'updateModf' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

19   updateModf:FormGroup;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Property '...' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49699067/property-has-no-initializer-and-is-not-definitely-assigned-in-the-construc)

Answer (score 0):

Move initializing to constructor as error message says.

Comment: i have do it , but the same prob