# How to initialize ElementRef Angular - Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

when I use

`@ViewChild('serachField', { static: false }) serachField: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>`

I get the error

```
Property 'serachField' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.
```

I usually initialise the variable, But I'm unsure how to do it  in this case

I've tried

```
@ViewChild('serachField', { static: false }) serachField: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement> = new ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>(--unsure what the parameter should be--)
```

I get:

```
Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554)
core.d.ts(2253, 17): An argument for 'nativeElement' was not provided.
```

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49699067/property-has-no-initializer-and-is-not-definitely-assigned-in-the-construc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49699067/property-has-no-initializer-and-is-not-definitely-assigned-in-the-construc)

Comment: is your **serachField** reference exists on the html view ? if yes then you have to provide the code where you access "nativeElement" property.. probably you should access it in **ngAfterViewInit** because you are using @ViewChild('serachField', **{ static: false }**)

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear question in sentence format.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Thank you @Isbn

I used:

```
@ViewChild('serachField', { static: false }) serachField: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement> = {} as ElementRef;
```

Comment: Thanx a 1,000,000 for that. It helped me too! Could you please accept your own answer, just to make it clear to others who read this question in future?