# ngx-bootstrap modal - Property 'modalRef' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import { BsModalService, BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';

export class PatchListComponent implements OnInit {

   modalRef: BsModalRef;

   constructor(private modalService: BsModalService) {
       openModal(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
           this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template);
       }
   }
}
```

Module:

```
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    ModalModule.forRoot(),
  ]
})
export class MyModule { }
```

Getting the following error :

> Property 'modalRef' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Property '...' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49699067/property-has-no-initializer-and-is-not-definitely-assigned-in-the-construc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This warning is prompted as **strictPropertyInitialization is enabled in tsconfig.json** and you **don't initialize the value for `modalRef`**.

> Property 'modalRef' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor

Meanwhile, you should not define `openModal` function inside `constructor`. This method will be inaccessible when another component needs to call this method for showing modal.

---

### SOLUTION

1. If you don't want to initialize `modalRef`, you can do in this way:

```
modalRef?: BsModalRef;
```

2. Move out `openModal` function from `constructor`.

> component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import { BsModalService, BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';

export class PatchListComponent implements OnInit {

    modalRef?: BsModalRef;

    constructor(private modalService: BsModalService) {}

    openModal(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
       this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template);
    }
}
```

---

### REFERENCES

[Ngx-Bootstrap - Modals](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ngx_bootstrap/ngx_bootstrap_modals.htm)

Comment: Thanks, it works.  
openModal function is not in constructor