# Input on Angular Component throwing error

Tags: angular

I am new to angular.

On the project I created a component named as button and on the `button.components.ts` file I added the code of `Input` on `import { Component, OnInit, **Input** } from '@angular/core';` and then afterwards I added the following code just above the button.component.ts constructor

```
@Input() text:string;
```

But it is throwing me an error on the word **text**, the error says,

> Property 'text' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor

The full code of the button.component.ts is as follows,

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

   @Component({
   selector: 'app-button',
   templateUrl: './button.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./button.component.css']
   })
   export class ButtonComponent implements OnInit {
  
   @Input() text:string;

   constructor() { }

   ngOnInit(): void {
   }

   }
```

Referring to the link shared by @Rohith V when I initialize the text value inside the constructor it throws me an error on another component where I have called this button component.

Throws me an error on a component named as header.component.html

```
<header>
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<app-button color="green" **text**="Add"></app-button>
</header>
```

The error says

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'any[]'

The updated button.component.ts is as follows,

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

   @Component({
   selector: 'app-button',
   templateUrl: './button.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./button.component.css']
   })
   export class ButtonComponent implements OnInit {
  
   @Input() text:any[];

   constructor() {
   this.text = [];
   }

   ngOnInit(): void {
   }

   }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49699067/property-has-no-initializer-and-is-not-definitely-assigned-in-the-construc

Have a look on this post and it is already answered here

Comment: @RohithV Question updated

Comment: Check https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mkbtfk url you will get your answer

Comment: @SurajTripathi That was still causing the error but when I initialized the Input var into the `constructor` like `this.text = '';` it removed the error. Just added a empty string value to that. I am not sure if that's the correct workaround to this problem but anyway it solved it