# Can not return custom object in ES6 class's constructor in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, constructor, attributes

How can we return custom object in Typescript's class constructor if that class has some required attribute. Below is example snippet for my situation in Typescript.

```js
class MyError extends Error {
    customRequiredAttribute: string[];

    constructor(error: any) {
        if (error instanceof MyError) {
            return error;
        } else {
            // do something else to initialize this instance
            super(error);
            this.customRequiredAttribute = [error.message];
        }
    }
}
```

Please see in the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBRATsg9s6BTAHgFywDsATGFdTAbwCho7pgBXCPNAWwCUsBHRgS2RZiAQTx5kfAEaMCALmgsJhAOYBtALoBuarXrA0hRY2CtkACiyoM8sIXgBKaDXovofAGbQLVzH0N5bYCw0TwRyDEdnV2jBPEZkQmwfbWi6AF9sEAgsJ11U+ghGAAdLbwp7FPz6PAALPggAOiYWdi5eASFRcSkZHIBeaFVLCga2LCgwZSwtPNc02fm0oA).

Above Typescript snippet will produce the following error:

```
Property 'customRequiredAttribute' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.
```

While in Javascript, we can achieve that:

```js
class MyError extends Error {
    constructor(error) {
        if (error instanceof MyError) {
            return error;
        } else {
            // do something else to initialize this instance
            super(error);
            this.customRequiredAttribute = [error.message];
        }
    }
}

const MyErrorFromNativeError = new MyError(new Error('has some error'));
const MyErrorFromMyError = new MyError(MyErrorFromNativeError);

console.log("Is both MyError above the same:", MyErrorFromMyError === MyErrorFromNativeError);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Property '...' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49699067/property-has-no-initializer-and-is-not-definitely-assigned-in-the-construc)

Comment: Sorry no. That question was missing initialize the required attribute. I am not missing the initialize, I want to return custom instance so current initialize will be skip.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with **Strict Class Checking** of the TS system. It requires the script to initialize all properties in the constructor. (The global setting is in `strictPropertyInitialization` flag of the tsconfig)

The best way to get around this error is by initializing the properties.

`customRequiredAttribute: string[] = '';`

However, this is not applicable in the current scenario as `super()` statement is not the first item in your constructor.

So, the work around is to disable Strict Class Checking for this property by using the `!` syntax.

`customRequiredAttribute!: string[];`

Comment: So as I understand, this is limited of Typescript and there is no way achieve this without type assertion. Am I correct?