# Property 'employeeForm' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor

Tags: angular

I am creating basic angular reactiveForm but i am getting an errow
Property 'employeeForm' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor

I followed to set false to the strict in tsconfig.json. When i do this the error dissapears but sand the code gets compiled successfuly but the employeeForm property was underlined with the same error  and the programs runs successfully but i when i console the formgroup elemmnts they are not displyed in the console.

That means it is now working. i feel this is because of this error.

Please help me how to intialize the formGruop  elements at the time time of declaration or else your own ideas.

[[image: create-employee.component.html1]

[image: create-employee.component.ts]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Property '...' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49699067/property-has-no-initializer-and-is-not-definitely-assigned-in-the-construc)

Answer (score 0):

> You need to use

```
employeeForm!: FormGroup();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should move the initialization of employeeForm inside the constructor:

```
employeeForm: FormGroup;

constructor() {
  this.employeeForm = new FormGroup({...});
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ciao. Why can't we use the same in the ngOnit() life cycle hook as i used earlier.

Comment: this comment is the perfect answer to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60113028/8115465