# Why passing element: { type: string, name: string, content: string }; doesn't work?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying the access element But it's showing an error

> Property 'element' has no initializer

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-server-element',
  templateUrl: './server-element.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./server-element.component.css']
  })
 export class ServerElementComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input('srvElement') element: {type: string, name: string, content: string};     <--- This doesn't work

constructor() { }

ngOnInit() { }

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Property '...' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49699067/property-has-no-initializer-and-is-not-definitely-assigned-in-the-construc)

Answer (score 2):

Provide some default value for `element` input or place [exclamation mark](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) after this `@Input('srvElement') element!: {type: string, name: string, content: string};` if You're sure that value will be provided. I don't recommend to set `"strictPropertyInitialization": false` because it's very useful to see not initialized values when we don't expect them to be. It can save you runtime problems in future.