# angular Property 'appareilStatus' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor

Tags: angular

**hi everyone ,i'am begginer in the angular framework , i  created the first component,but got an error someone can help me please,**

[image]

**here is the error in the console log**

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Property '...' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49699067/property-has-no-initializer-and-is-not-definitely-assigned-in-the-construc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to something called `strictPropertyInitialization` which is equal to `true` in **tsconfig.json**.

So we have to tell the compiler that this instance will be initialized during runtime.

We do that by adding the `!` operator to ignore strict type.

Your declaration will become like the following

`@Input() appareilName!: string;`

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

mate! Welcome on board!

The error is thrown by the linter due to the TypeScript rule `strictPropertyInitialization`.
See: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictPropertyInitialization

> When set to true, TypeScript will raise an error when a class property
> was declared but not set in the constructor.

The problem with your code is that you've type the `appareilStatus` as a `string`, but did not make sure that the variable is actually defined.
In the case that your component `appareilStatus` is used without the input, that variable will be `undefined` and therefore not a `string`.

```html
<app-appareil></app-appareil>
instead of your intended
<app-appareil appareilStatus="..." [appareilName]="'...'"></app-appareil>
```

To solve this error you have multiple options:

1. Add `undefined` to the types: `@Input() appareilStatus: string | undefined`
2. Mark `appareilStatus` as an optional parameter `@Input() appareilStatus?: string`
3. Initialize your variable with a default value: `@Input() appareilStatus: string = ''`
4. Initialize your variable in the constructor

```js
@Input() appareilStatus: string

constructor() {
  this.appareilStatus = 'add your logic here';
}
```

5. Not recommended: suppress the error in that line by adding `// @ts-ignore` in the line before
6. Use a non-null assertion and mark your variable as "never undefined" if you intend this field as a required input: `@Input() appareilStatus: string`

or... if you are annoying by this rule for now. You can disable this check by adding `"strictPropertyInitialization": false` to your `tsconfig.json`

Comment: Oh! Just noticed that Mohamed.Karkotly already answered your question in the meantime. Just note that the `!` will actually mark this field required for the compiler. In that case it will not warn you about potential errors later on like `Object is possibly 'undefined'.` if you try to do `this. appareilName.indexOf('something')` for example, which would fail, if `appareilName` is `undefined`.

Comment: You answered that better, good job!