# How to initialize a property through a setter in the constructor?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using angular framework and here is my class structure:

```
export class Demo {
  _name: string;

  constructor(inputName: string) {
    this.name = inputName;
  }

  public set name(inputName: string) {
    this._name = `%${inputName}%`;
  }

  public get name(): string {
    return this._name;
  }
}
```

And it give me an error:

> Property '_name' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

How can I prevent it?

Comment: Fix the variable name in the constructor.

Comment: @R.Richards I have some processing in the setter, if i just set the value to _name directly, It will bypass the processing.

Comment: Just Googled your error, and it seems like your question is [a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49699097/19330634). Please DYOR

Comment: @l-_-l Nope. I'm not attempt to declare a porperty without initialize. I'm asking how can I initialize a property through a setter in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options

**Option 1:**

use `!` to tell [TypeScript's Strict Class Initialization](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#strict-class-initialization) that it's OK not to initialize `_name`

```ts
_name!: string;
  // ^
  // Notice this '!' modifier.
  // This is the "definite assignment assertion"
```

**Option 2:**

Set `_name` in the constructor "correctly"

```ts
  constructor(inputName: string) {
    this._name = inputName; // _name, not name
  }
```

**Option 3:**

Initialize `_name` to a default string value. This will ensure that the `_name` is never something other than a `string`. If you don't set it, `_name` can be `undefined`.

```
_name: string = '';
```

Comment: Option 1 did fix the error , just a little bit wire because I already initialize it through the setter. So does it mean I have to initialize the property directly in the constructor?

Comment: That’s not your only option, but I don’t think you can do it through a function (setter) in the constructor. You need to do any of the options I described, or take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49699097/19330634