# Angular 13 ElementRef initialization error

Tags: angular

hello i am having issues initializing viewchild elementRef
this always work fine for me but in angular 13 i am having an error message

```
 @ViewChild("text", { static: true }) text : ElementRef;
```

> Property 'text' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to.

```
@ViewChild("text", { static: true }) text!: ElementRef;
```

Read more

1. [Property 'text' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49699067/property-has-no-initializer-and-is-not-definitely-assigned-in-the-construc)
2. [Not null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator)

Comment: hello thanks, this suppressed the error but i couldnt call nativeElement

Comment: hello i referenced the still thesame, i coudnt access the nativeElement

Comment: hello thanks it actually worked, i was making the test in my constructor instead of ngOnInit