# TypeScript Define an Array

Tags: angular, typescript

im new to TS and wondering how to make this work,

```
products: any;

ngOnInit() {
        this.productService.getProducts().subscribe(data => this.products = data);
        console.log(this.products)
    }
```

By declaring products "any" this works just fine but products is undefined. Later in the code i will need products to be defined becouse of this ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'trim').

So i tried this

```
products = new Array<Object>();

ngOnInit() {
       this.productService.getProducts().subscribe(data => this.products = data);
       console.log(this.products)
   }
```

this says that Type `'Object' is not assignable to type 'Object[]'`

another try

```
products: { id: number, cislo: string, nazov: string}[];

ngOnInit() {
        this.productService.getProducts().subscribe(data => this.products = data);
        console.log(this.products)
    }
```

this follows with

`Property 'products' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.`

what way sould i declare products so they will be defined?

.... EDIT

getProducts looks like

```
getProducts() {
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/zakon/getAListOfAll');
    }
```

and it returns this json

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "cislo": "0/0",
    "nazov": "bez zakona"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "cislo": "156/25",
    "nazov": "zakon 165 o niecom z roku 123"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "cislo": "222/22",
    "nazov": "zakon 166 o niecom z roku 1234"
  }
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Property '...' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49699067/property-has-no-initializer-and-is-not-definitely-assigned-in-the-construc)

Comment: And also `console.log()` will not give you the desired output as it's outside of the async call to the `productService.getProducts()`

Comment: Please share response of getProducts.

Comment: It sounds like i does but now i have declared products to be array but when i load data into it `Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'any[]'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    export interface Product : { 
    id: number, 
    cislo: string,
     nazov: string
    }
    //@Component....
    
    products:Product[]=[]
    
    ngOnInit() {
             this.getProducts()  
        
               
            }

getProducts(){
this.productService.getProducts().subscribe(
        (data:Product[] )=> {
         this.products = data
         console.log(this.products)
        })
}
```

Comment: ```No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(observer?: Partial<Observer<Object>> | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
    Type '(data: Product[]) => void' has no properties in common with type 'Partial<Observer<Object>>'.```   Error on data:Product[]

Comment: verify the shape of data returned by the backend  just console.log("data",data) ..verify that data has the same shape of product interface (array of object)

Comment: I solve it by making variables in interface optional lise so `id?:number;` but im accepting your answer couse it led me to the solution, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
products: { id: number, cislo: string, nazov: string}[];

ngOnInit() {
    this.productService.getProducts().subscribe(data => {
      this.products = data;
      console.log(this.products);
    });
}
```

You are accessing `products` outside the callback function. As it will log `this.products` like a static code here where the api call is async.
Try it this way and access it inside the callback function.