# How to hide navigation side bar in Login page in angular 4 project.?

Tags: javascript, angular, navigationbar, angular4-router

I am new to angular 4 projects.  So far I found that other answers given for separate navigation bar and render a page, but my one is all content pages are embedded and render within the navigation bar page. so I put `<router-outlet>` within navigation page, that didn't off nav bar. If I give the `<router-outlet>` in app-component, it renders pages individually and not within nav bar. My code is below.

index.html

```
<body>
    <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

app.component.html

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar> 
<app-loginpage></app-loginpage>
```

app.module.ts

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path:'', redirectTo:'/loginpage',pathMatch:'full'},
  { path:'loginpage', component: LoginpageComponent  },
  { path:'navbar', component: NavbarComponent  },
  { path:'product', component: ProductComponent  },];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent  ,
    LoginpageComponent,
    ProductComponent,],
imports: [   
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]

})
export class AppModule { }
```

login.component.html

```
    <div class="login">
    <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control "  name="UserName" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control "  name="password"/> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-md-push-6 text-center">
   <a routerLink="/product" routerLinkActive="active"><button id="Enter" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat fa fa-sign-in" > Log-In</button> </a>
    </div>
    </div>
```

navbar.component.html

```
<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini" id="navigationbar" >
<div class="wrapper "  >
    <header class="main-header">
(logo desings)  </header>
 <aside class="main-sidebar">
{nav side bar designs} </aside>
<div class="content-wrapper">
   <section class="content admin_table">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>      
    </section>  </div>
  <footer class="main-footer">
{footer design}
</footer>
</body>
```

router link to `/product` page is a normal page that must be rendered within the navbar page. currently, Product page design is

`<p> Product Page Works </p>`

Since all answers I searched in stack overflow were available for different nav bar and different content page. But my one is content pages embedded within the nav bar page. 
Even I tried the answer of [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43118592/angular-2-how-to-hide-nav-bar-in-some-components). As my one is embedded, it hides nav bar for all pages.