# Show items based on visible component

Tags: angular, angular-components

I'm new to Angular and I need some advice

I'm using a bootstrap navbar (ul and li elements) in a header component and a router outlet.

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I want to hide and show certain navbar items based on the component that is currently showing. What is the best practice to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not best practice as I just came up with it but here is my try: 
You can inject the `Router` in your AppHeaderComponent and do something like this:

```
export class AppHeaderComponent {
    currentRoute$: Observable<string>;
    showPostsNavbarItems$: Observable<boolean>;
    constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {


        this.currentRoute$ = router.events.pipe(
            filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
            pluck('urlAfterRedirects')
        );
        this.showPostsNavbarItems$ = this.currentRoute$.pipe(
            map(route => route === 'whatever')
        );
    }
}
```

So you can use the  `*ngIf` + `async` pipe in your template to show/hide them.

I am not sure how the url in event.urlAfiterRedirects looks like though, I haven't tried it yet.

I hope I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this solution.

I have create a demo on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/how-to-hide-navigation-side-bar-in-login-page-in-angular-4-proj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

```
<div class="container">
<app-side-nav *ngIf="blankUrl || !isCheckoutRoute()"></app-side-nav>

<div id="main">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>

</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**There are two ways to do so.**

> 1. Make it condition based. Show it when you want it using ***ngIf**.

Please see this answer for more - [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43118592/angular-2-how-to-hide-nav-bar-in-some-components).

> 2. The second and the best ways is to handle this with the **modules**.

Make a different module which does not include navbar and put the components which not require navbar. And rest of the components in the module which requires navbar.

Answer (score 1):

If the items is dynamic flow this 
You can create a global service has an public poperty with type of array , and render this array of item on navbar

second step in each componet inject the global service and at ngOninit method assaing new item to the service , so every time navbar will have current component items.

if the items is already render in navbar 
just create a global service with property of string , this property like flag, at ngOninit method assign component flag value like this  'home','admin','setting'

```
<ul>
<li *ngIf="globalService.selectdFlag === 'home'">home 01</li>
<li *ngIf="globalService.selectdFlag === 'home'">home 02</li>
<li *ngIf="globalService.selectdFlag === 'admin'">admin 01</li>
<li *ngIf="globalService.selectdFlag === 'admin'">steeing 01</li>
<li *ngIf="globalService.selectdFlag === 'setting'">setting 01</li>
</ul>
```

Happy Coding