# How to create a component which doesn't contain my navigation in angular 7?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-components

I need to create a component, where you don't have the navigation on top included, but I don't know how. I read, that every component you create is a child component of the appcomponent. In the `app.component.html` it is definded, that the navigation is on top and then comes the content. Also the component needs to be accessed over a route defined in `app-routing.module.ts`. Can anyone help?

`app.component.html`:

```
<app-navigation></app-navigation>

<div id="content">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43118592/angular-2-how-to-hide-nav-bar-in-some-components

Comment: Instead of using `app-navigation` in `app.component`, include it in individual routes so that you can avoid it in places as per required.

Answer (score 0):

So basically you'll need a way to communicate back from **child-component** to **parent-component**.

Angular provides a way, using the **Output** decorator and **EventEmitter**. In the child component declare a property, something like

```
  @Output() 
  hideTopMenu = new EventEmitter();
```

and in the **ngOnInit** of **child-component** you may write

```
this.hideTopMenu.emit(true);
```

In the **router-outlet** of **parent component**, handle the **(activate)** event,

```
<router-outlet (activate)="onActivate($event)"></router-outlet>
```

The activate method would go like this

```
//the reference of current component is provided to the method.
onActivate(componentReference)
{
//check if this component had the output-emitter.
 if(componentReference.hideTopMenu)
 {
  componentReference.hideTopMenu.subscribe((data) => {
   if(data)
   {
     // hide menu logic may go here, maybe you set a boolean value and on template you set *ngIf on menu.
   }
  })
}
}
```

Thanks.