# Hide the content of app.component file from a single component in Angular

Tags: angular

So I am trying to create an Angular app which will ask you to log in before accessing it. I am trying to keep the navbar in the app.component file so it is reused on all the components, but I want to get rid of it on the login page. I thought of just hiding it using CSS, but that might pose a security risk since the navbar will have other routes as well.

I was also thinking of leaving the app.component idea and creat a child navbar component which will be reused in every component, but I'm not sure if that's the best way to do this. Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: the navbar being accessible should NEVER pose a security risk. there's no such thing as front end security. hiding things with css vs javascript should be a performance based decision, NEVER a security based decision.

Comment: Check out this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43118592/angular-2-how-to-hide-nav-bar-in-some-components

Answer (score 0):

**I believe you are having login component in router outlet. Update it like**

```
<nav-bar *ngIf="showNavBar"></nav-bar>
<router-outlet (activate)="toggleNavBar($event)"></router-outlet>
```

**in app component**

```
public showNavBar = true;

toggleNavBar(component) {
   if(component instanceof LoginComponent) {
      this.showNavBar = false;
   } else {
      this.showNavBar = true;
   }
}
```