# Angular 2 Access parent component variables with dynamic children

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to create an editable form component.  I've looked at several answers on how to access parent data, but none of them answer the question which will fit these needs:

1. There can be multiple form component's on the same page, (this means I cannot use a global service to control this)
2. I do not know what form components will be added ahead of time.  (this means that I will not be able to include them in the parent template)

Lets say I have an interface:

```
export interface EditOptions
{
    isEditing: boolean;
}
```

Now lets say I have a component with a button which controls the editing status like so:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { EditOptions } from '../../../models/editOptions';

@Component({
  selector: 'editable-form',
  templateUrl: '<div><button (click)="toggleEdit()">Edit</button></div>'
})
export class EditableFormComponent {
    editOptions: EditOptions = { isEditing: false };
    isEditing: boolean = false;

    toggleEdit() {
        this.editOptions.isEditing = !this.editOptions.isEditing;
    }

    getEditOptions() {
        return this.editOptions;
    }
}
```

Now Lets say I have a Child Component:

```
<div>
  <div [hidden]="!editOptions.isEditing">
    <input #inlineEditControl [required]="required" [name]="value" [(ngModel)]="value" [type]="type" [placeholder]="label" />
  </div>
  <div [hidden]="editOptions.isEditing">
    <label class="block bold">{{label}}</label>
    <div class="inline-edit">{{value}}&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the typescript file, (For simplicity issue's i've ommited the full code):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'inline-edit',
  templateUrl: 'inline-edit.html'
})
export class InlineEditComponent{
     @Input() editOptions: EditOptions;
     @Input() label: string;
     @Input() value: string;
}
```

Now I Can Construct a page like so:

```
<div>
    <editable-form #profileForm></editable-form>
    <inline-edit [(ngModel)]='user.username' [editOptions]='#profileForm.getEditOptions()'></inline-edit>
</div>
```

This works but I would like it to work so the parent controls everything is there a way I can do this instead:

```
<div>
    <editable-form #profileForm><inline-edit [(ngModel)]='user.username'></inline-edit></editable-form>
</div>
```

and then have the editable form component some how grab out all of the view children and set the editOptions from a list instead?

Comment: I think this is what you want: [subscriptions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42423403/angular-2-notify-a-route-component-of-an-event-in-the-app-component)

Comment: @Sam yeah kinda but in this case there would be no global service, each component is dependent on its parent.